# mediapipe KNIFT template matching example: using own pics doesn not work properly - how does the example actually work?

Tags: mediapipe

i followed the example steps to create an own android app KNIFT template matching example like the 3 dollar bill example on the mediapipe website...did anyone of you build this and know how this really works? I cant get a clear documentation.

My approach to run my own example as suggested on the mediapipe: I have three example pics in my folder (and I did all the build steps with them) that are detected and framed indeed....but not as often and not as correctly as in the dollar bill example (which works fine for me, every bill is detected and framed and labeled as expected).
Also my labeling doesnt work properly. Sometimes it does partly, sometimes it is labeled but incorrect. What does the framework do with my pics and labels and how to optimize my own example?
Any help is appreciated...
regards, fabian

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.